# google maps api key what to use

Tags: api, maps

I don't get it, why do I need an API KEY?/

If I place map code into my site using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

it works.

If I place code into my site using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=flase"></script>
```

where API_KEY is my api key it also works.

What is the difference here? Which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key to function.

However, Google says you *should* use an API key to [monitor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) your usage. In case you exceed your usage limits, you'll know about it and Google can contact you.

The [usage limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits) is 25,000 map loads/day/API.